# Help expressing Logs in natural log and then simplifying

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need some help changing regular Logs->Ln, and then simplifying it. I made a post last night, but must of made a mistake.

Here are the problems,

Express as ratio's of natural logs and simplify

3: $\log_9(X)/\log_3(X)$.

Here is a picture of the problems. 
[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/5zj2q.png[/IMG]

I am not really sure how to go about solving it, as they have different bases. I tried the first one and I got (lnx/ln3)/(ln9/lnx) and not really sure where to go from there.

Thanks!

Comment: [What was the mistake?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665557/calc-1-log-and-expression-simplify-help) I think what those users wanted was to see what kind of work you had done on the problem. If that's the case, you might consider editing one of these posts and deleting the other.

Comment: ah ok, not sure how to  delete the other thread. But so far the work I have done is I just worked on the first one and I got (lnx/ln3)/(ln9/lnx) but not sure where to go from there. I think the change base formula may be needed? That is what I used to get  my "answer".

Comment: Did I seem to do it correctly? I asked the mods to lock the other thread/delete it. Hopefully I did this one correctly?

Comment: I left a few hints for you last night on the other post. Did you use any of them? The hint for your $\log_9 x / \log_3 x$ problem doesn't require the change-of-base formula, but if you want to use it, note that one of your fractions is upside-down.

Comment: yea i did, just went back and did it using your way and i got the same answer as below.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did it right. Here is the detailed calculations.
$$
\frac{\log_9(X)}{\log_3(X)}=\frac{\log(X)/\log(9)}{\log(X)/\log(3)}
=\frac{\log(X)}{\log(9)} \cdot \frac{\log(3)}{\log(X)}=\frac{\log(3)}{\log(9)}
=\frac{\log(3)}{\log(3^2)}=\frac{\log(3)}{2\log(3)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Note that it does not matter what base $\log$ is taken.

Comment: ah ok. so for log_√10 X/ log_√2 X I got up to ln√2/ln√10 can i go any further? cant really square both, and ln√10 can only simplify into more roots.